# native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist build

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, module

I have an old react native project, when I relaunch it and the result is the same error as above. I tried npm install again and reinstall react-native-community/cli-platform-android package.
Please help me with this problem, thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuSuq.png)